# How do I fill and center an image uinsg CSS?

Tags: css, image

I have an image of arbitrary shape and size which I want to enlarge into a containing div without changing its proportions and without cutting off part of the image.

Below is a diagram of what I have in mind:

[image]

[image]

Note that the image is sometimes centred vertically, and sometime horizontally.

If the image is always wide, I can use:

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
```

but that won’t work if the image is narrower, as it will end up chopping off the top & bottom.

Is there a way, possibly using grid or flex, which will accommodate the image?

Comment: Use `object-fit` if your container as a fixed size: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit. There is no need to use flex/grid.

Comment: Thanks @Terry. However, it took me a long time to work out that I also need to include `object-fit: contain; width: 100%; height: 100%;`. That much isn’t obvious from the documentation or other example I found floating on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Terry’s comment, I found a solution using `object-fit`.

```css
    div#container {
      background-color: #123456;
      width: 480px;
      height: 240px;
    }
    div#container>img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      <img src="https://javascript101.webcraft101.com/images/photos/large/bromeliad.jpg" alt="Random" title="Random Image">
    </div>
```

The main features are:

- `object-fit` describes how the image is positioned within its container. In this case, it is wholly contained, and ends up being centred in the process, while retaining its proportions.
- The `width` and `height` are set to `100%` (of the container). I *think* this forces the image to scale into the container.

What a wonderful property!

Answer (score 0):

Use `object-fit: contain` for the `img` selector in the `css`,

- your `<img>` tag will be your gray frame like in above.
- the real picture will be hosted as you wish no matter what the intrinsic size of the image is and the size of the `<img>` tag is.